# TinyXML getting Value

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, tinyxml

given XML like:

```
<a>
    <result>0</result>
    <data>I9C3J9N3cCTZdKGK+itJW1Q==</data>
</a>
```

I need to get the fact that `<result>` is 0 and act upon it.

I am doing:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
bool bOK = doc.Parse((const char*)chunk.memory, 0, TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8);
if (bOK)
{
    TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
    TiXmlElement *pRoot, *pParm, *pParm2;
    pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("a");
    if(pRoot)
    {
        pParm = pRoot->FirstChildElement("result");
        if (pParm)
        {
            if (pParm->GetText()=="0")
            {
                pParm2 = pRoot->NextSiblingElement("data");
                if (pParm2)
                {
                    sValue = pParm2->GetText();
                    std::cout << "sValue: " << sValue << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that `GetText()` was the right answer, but I am doing something wrong because I never get inside the `if` to check the `<data>` element.

Can anyone shed some light for me?

Comment: TinyXML has the option of compiling with it using `std::string` rather than char buffers. You may want to specify which way you're using it, as it will affect a potential bug in your string comparison.

Comment: I do have `#define TIXML_USE_STL` in my PCH

Comment: all I did to make was execute `make` and it built

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your case, `<data>` isn't Sibling of `<a>`.

You're checking **pRoot**->NextSiblingElement("data") while you should check for **pParm**->NextSiblingElement("data");

You could also change it to

```
pParm2 = pRoot->FirstChildElement("data");
```

**Edit:**
Sorry, i thought you were referring to this if:

```
if (pParm2)
```

So, the solution could be this:

```
if (std::string(pParm->GetText())=="0")
```

or

```
if (strcmp(pParm->GetText(), "0"))
```

You choose. I prefer the first one.

**Edit 2:**

I'm really sorry, I was forgetting that strcmp return the first position of where the 2 strings are the same, so, in your case it should be:

```
if (strcmp(pParm->GetText(), "0") == 0)
```

You need to include `<string.h>` too.

Comment: I see, but I am not getting into `if (pParm->GetText()=="0")` so I think that there is something wrong in the compare to 0

Comment: @Jason that was the bug I was referring to. You *can* build TinyXML to use the standard library and such things as `std::string` become the types for things like `GetText()`. it is a single compiler flag. Without it you must to the lifting yourself for things like string comparisons (as you've just found out).